# Sharing a video via intent to messaging apps like Viber

Tags: java, android, android-intent, viber

With this code i want to share an MP4 video to messaging apps like WhatsApp, Viber, Line etc. but only WhatsApp can do it successfully, But for Example if i choose Viber, After selecting recipient nothing happens, Screen flashes and nothing happens. how i can fix it?

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, Uri.parse(String.valueOf(path)));
    intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(String.valueOf(path)), "video/*");
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(String.valueOf(path)));
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share video using"));
```

Comment: Start by getting rid of the second parameter to your `Intent` constructor. `ACTION_SEND` does not use a `Uri` that way: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND

Comment: @CommonsWare: i do that, But does not change anything